# Why don't I have a camera on my iPod touch?

Tags: ipod-touch

Why do a couple of my friends have a camera on their iPod touch and I don't?

Comment: They also have a better screen, the fabled retina display...

Answer (score 11):

As far as I know, only the 4th gen iPod touch has a camera. Yours is probably older.

As you can see from the specifications published on Apple's site, there are no mention of a camera for the [third gen iPod touch](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP570), while [the fourth gen](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP594) has detailed information about it.

Comment: two cameras, right?

Comment: Yes, there is a back camera and a front camera.

Answer (score 3):

Only the 4th generation iPod Touch has cameras, that is the iPod Touch that was introduced back in September. The iPod Touch you have is either a 1st, 2nd, or 3rd generation, which means it doesn't have the camera.